# Embed php in html to keep text in text box after user submits a value

Tags: php, html, post

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost/index1.php" method="post">
    Type your name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

What I was trying to do is keep the data entered in the textbox after the user inputs a value and presses the submit button.

When I press the submit button it gives a notice in the text box saying that name is
an undefined index which I understand why. $_POST['name'] does not have a value.

I was just wondering if there is a way to do this. 
I am beginner with php and HTML.

Comment: Everybody please read this - http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2012/03/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-cross-site-scripting-xss-in-php-part-1-how-not-to-use-htmlspecialchars-for-output-escaping/

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
//check whether the variable $_POST['name'] exists
//this condition will be false for the loading
if(isset($_POST['name']){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
}
else{
  //if the $_POST['name'] is not set
  $name = '';
}


?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost/index1.php" method="post">
    Type your name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (assuming this is `index1.php` and you're using `UTF-8` for your content type)

```
<?php
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
?>

<!-- your HTML, form, etc -->

<input type="text" name="name"
    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>">
```

Comment: isset is not the right way of doing it, you have to check if 'name' key is in the $_POST array.

Comment: @AsTeR Perhaps you are unaware of what `isset()` does. I suggest you [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php#example-4825)

Answer (score 1):

From @Phil's answer considering that's using "isset" is not the solution (**EDIT** : I'm wrong on this point see comments), the right function is to test $_POST as the "name" entry your are trying to access:

```
<?php
$name = null;
if (array_key_exists('name', $_POST)) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
//more condensed : $name = array_key_exists('name', $_POST) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
?>

<!-- your HTML, form, etc -->

<input type="text" name="name"
    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>">
```

The message that appears is a PHP warning, reading about [your environment error_reporting in PHP](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-reporting.php) might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

@Dallas

You're on the right track; here is a (*very* rough and dirty) example form which displays the value of the submitted POST field in its original textbox

```
<form action="thispage.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="mytext" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['mytext'])?$_POST['mytext']:''?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

What this does is check that the POST field, `mytext`, is defined and (if so) puts that value back into the textbox. If it isn't defined, it just gives a blank value.

If it isn't working for you, I'd doublecheck the `name` attribute of your textbox matches the key value you're searching for in $_POST.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed I forgot the isset around the POST. Fixed

Comment: I assume the down-vote is because your suggestion exposes a very simple and naive injection attack. Recreate this form and then post it with the content `<script>alert('pwned');</script>` and let us know what happens.

Comment: Heh, I did say it was rough and dirty; You are right, of course.

Comment: I'm not sure that considering every XSS attack opportunities in something that looks like a PHP Hello World is a really good point.

Answer (score 0):

As your form action attribute is pointing to index1.php then I assume that the given HTML code is given in same index1.php, in that case,then you have to do this

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost/index1.php" method="post">
    Type your name: input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){echo $_POST['name'];}?>
                    input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

`<?php echo isset($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:''?>` is the another way to make the value attribute conditional